# What is the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^4(1+x+x^2+...)^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I got
$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^4=x^4((1-x^5)/1-x)^4$$
and
$$(1+x+x^2+...)^4=1/(1-x)^4,$$
what I should do next? Please help me with it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write the $x^n$ coefficient in $f(x)$ as $[x^n]f(x)$. You want$$[x^7](1-x^5)^4(1-x)^{-8}=[x^7](1-x)^{-8}-4[x^2](1-x)^{-8}.$$You can do the rest with the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).